# Background image scrolls in IOS Mobile

Tags: css

I have this website. I want a static background in IOS Mobile too.

> http://www.mattvella.com/staging/reviews.php

The background image is static and fixed in all cases **but it scrolls in IOS Mobile**. I don't even have ios so I don't know what the case may be. I have tried many solutions but none seem to be working for me.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors in your CSS stylings for the body that may be having some effect. Try updating your `body` style to be:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../media/images/mv-background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: Columbia;
}
```

Inside your media queries, try updating your stylings to include:

```
body {
    /* other properties here */
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: When I place this inside me media query, the position of background image gets disturbed.

Comment: and it is still scrolling for ios mobile

Comment: Your media queries don't appear to include `background-attachment: fixed`. That is pretty important to prevent scrolling.

Comment: I placed body { background-attachment: fixed; } at the end of my css and tried but it still scrolls on iphone.